# running sbt new pointing to internal organization's github

Tags: scala, sbt, giter8

if I
 run [sbt new](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/sbt-new-and-Templates.html#Trying+new+command) x/y.g8, it supplies args to giter8 and giter8 connects to github.com and downloads the template.

I would like to build a template for my team internal to my company. We are using github.company.com as internal github. Is there anyway to make sbt/giter8 understand to search not only github.com but also github.company.com as well.

I tried specifying full url like below but it isn't working

sbt new https://github.company.com/AnalyticsEngineeringAdmin/spark-template.g8

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to make it work by running
sbt new https://github.company.com/AnalyticsEngineeringAdmin/giter8.g8

Instead of using normal password, I used a Personal Access Token to make it work.